# custom resest password authentication in flutterflow

Tags: firebase-authentication, flutterflow

I want that link mailed to reset password should navigate user to create new password page of the app,and the password entered on this page should override forgotten(previous password ) in firebase .

I know how to do default firebase auth in flutterflow but dont know how to do this custom reset password auth in flutterflow